# AP63203 Buck not working

Tags: power, power-electronics, switch-mode-power-supply, dc-dc-converter, buck

Recently I have been experimenting with the [AP63203](https://www.diodes.com/assets/Datasheets/AP63200-AP63201-AP63203-AP63205.pdf), and I just have not been able to get it to output 3.3V successfully. Currently, the way I have been testing it is using an SMT to TH adapter, which I have soldered the buck to and stuck it on a breadboard along with the \$4.7 \mu\text{H}\$ inductor  and the other capacitors based on the diagram below:
[image]

I have stuck with the recommended values as outlined in the datasheet, except for the inductor, as I don't have a \$3.9 \mu\text{H}\$ one.

With the first test, I supplied 24V to the input and noted that the power supply was shoring out. I tested the pins on the buck and realised that pins 4, 3 and 5 (`GND`, `VIN` and `SW`, respectively) are shorted together permanently, whether the buck had power or not.
(See the image below for the breadboard layout, the top left of the IC is pin 1).

[image]

I repeated this with a brand new buck converter and, this time kept the input and output grounds separated, and I found that all 6 pins were now at about 24V (with respect to input ground), and the power supply was not shorting. I also found that `GND` (output) was not permanently shorted to SW this time around, so I am not quite sure what is going on.
(See the image below for a slightly different layout where the grounds are separated).

[image]

I feel like I am making a very obvious mistake somewhere, but I can't see it, have I wired something incorrectly on my breadboard? If anyone could point me in the right direction, that would be greatly appreciated. TIA

Comment: Did you get the correct IC (3V§ Fixed) or the adjustable Version?

Comment: "_and this time kept the input and output grounds seperated_" - what does this mean? the IC only has one ground pin, and it's not going to produce an isolated output...

Comment: The marking on the IC is `T43SU`, and paring that up with page 16 of the datasheet, I can confirm that it correlates to `AP63203WU-7` - I am sure that it is the fixed variant. @ElectronicsStudent

Comment: It was mostly out of curiosity to see what would happen as I wasn't sure why `SW` and `GND` were permanently shorted. @Attie

Comment: Update: I found that `VIN` is also permanently tied to the `GND`, so makes sense why the power supply was shorting out.

Comment: @Лука If this is the case i would check the bread-board/the wiring .... The IC wont do that unless its a faulty part (which is unlikely)

Comment: I'm as confused as Attie about "kept the input and output grounds seperated". There is only one ground in the circuit. There nothing to separate... If you didn't connect the input ground to the rest of the circuit, then it's no surprise that the entire circuit measures 24V with respect to input ground.

Comment: There is no way anyone can decipher from the breadboard photos how things are connected together. Even if there was a schematic it would be hard to prove from a photo that the breadboard circuit matches the schematics.

Comment: That's true; apologies for that. I can confirm that I have everything connected as it should be after rigorously going over it. I have also tested the breadboard and it seems fine as well.

Comment: "_[...] (GND, VIN and SW, respectively) are shorted together permanently_" - this isn't right, try taking a brand new IC out of the packaging, and measuring it **before** powering it. If these pins are still a dead short (i.e: near zero resistance), then you may have faulty or fake parts. Where did you get them from?

Comment: Trying to breadboard this type of circuit is futile as you get stray inductances and connections with high resistance. The manufacturer specifies a pcb layout - this is not optional.

Comment: Yeah, it definitely wasn't right. @Attie I did test the buck before soldering them onto the adapter and found that they didn't have those issues. Not quite sure what I did that caused that. The parts were completely fine, (ordered from Digikey), the issue came down to the adapter not making sufficient contact with the breadboard pins, silly me. Thanks to everyone for all of the input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue. Turns out the SMT to TH adapter I have been using didn't have long pins to make contact with the breadboard (Silly mistake, I know). Holding down the IC to ensure sufficient contact fixed the issue immediately, confirming that you can experiment with this type of circuit on a breadboard despite it being a SMD.